# How to refer to an item within the Ansible when statement

Tags: ansible

In the `Ansible` playbooks is there something equivalent possible to the following?

```
- name: "Example"
  command: "./create_user.sh create {{ item.key }} {{ item.value.pwd }}"
  args:
    chdir: "/usr/local/bin/"
  with_dict: "{{ users }}"
  when:
    - verb == 'create'
    - profile in item.value['env']
```

Currently `Ansible` is choking with an error:

> FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'profile in item.value['env']' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (profile in item.value['env']): Unable to look up a name or access an attribute in template string ({% if profile in item.value['env'] %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}).\nMake sure your variable name does not contain invalid characters like '-': argument of type 'StrictUndefined' is not iterable\n\nThe error appears to have been in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop and delegate to an included task using loop_control. For example:

main.yml

```
- name: "Example"
  include_tasks: create-user.yml
  loop: "{{ users }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: user
```

create-user.yml (here the *item* is aliased as the variable `user` (and you could even loop on yet another variable if needed).

```
- name: create user
  command: "./create_user.sh create {{ user.key }} {{ user.value.pwd }}"
  args:
    chdir: "/usr/local/bin/"
  when:
    - verb == 'create'
    - profile in user.value['env']
```

I've never used this structure with a dict, but *it should work* (maybe with a small tweak).

Comment: I don't think this actually addresses the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a simple syntax error in your playbook. You're referring to a variable named `profile` but it does not exist. If you are checking to see if the literal string "profile" is contained in `item.value['env']`, you would write it like this:

```
- name: "Example"
  command: "./create_user.sh create {{ item.key }} {{ item.value.pwd }}"
  args:
    chdir: "/usr/local/bin/"
  with_dict: "{{ users }}"
  when:
    - verb == 'create'
    - "'profile' in item.value['env']"
```

If you're trying to use a variable named `profile`, you just need to ensure that it's defined first.  For example, this playbook, which is exactly what you have in your question, runs without error:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    users:
      alice:
        pwd: /home/alice
        env: ""
    verb: create
    profile: ""
  tasks:
    - name: "Example"
      command: "./create_user.sh create {{ item.key }} {{ item.value.pwd }}"
      args:
        chdir: "/usr/local/bin/"
      with_dict: "{{ users }}"
      when:
        - verb == 'create'
        - profile in item.value['env']
```

Comment: Thank you for your insights, but I have `profile` declared in the `group_vars` therefore it definitely exist.

Comment: I'm suspicious.  Your code, as written, works just fine for me if first define a `profile` variable.  See my update for details.

Comment: The bottom line was that I also have had `users` variable declared in the `group_vars`, which has overridden other `users` variable declared in the `defaults/main`... Therefore yes, my code works as it is, I just needed to rename the variable. The accepted answer works well in this scenario and helped me to spot the underlying issue.